# Draw a shape in GDI+ that overlays opaque pixels with transparency

Tags: .net, vb.net, gdi+, transparent, alpha

I have a mask bitmap (bmpMask) that I am drawing onto a destination bitmap (bmpDest). Both bitmaps have alpha channels but are already full of opaque content.

What I want to do is produce transparent areas using GDI+ 'Draw...' methods on bmpMask so that bmpDest shows through when I draw bmpMask over it.

Of course `gMask.DrawLine(Pens.Transparent, 0, y, wMax, y)` causes no change to bmpMask, because GDI+ works as designed and doesn't draw anything when transparent. Even with semitransparent colors, only the r,g,b values of bmpMask's pixels are updated.

But what I want to do is issue a draw method that will change the alpha channel of bmpMask so it is transparent when drawn onto bmpDest. I know I can do this with SetPixel or speedier unsafe or Marshall alternatives, but that would cause a much more complicated solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Found 'the' answer after 3 years!

I never did get around to trying Dan's solution, so I don't want to take away from it, but this does exactly what I want:

```
    ' (setting composting mode is the key to getting the transparent
    ' line to actually result in setting the pixels to transparent-
    ' instead of just not drawing anything 'because it's transparent dummy' - 
    ' because it turns off the 'math' that is done to cause transparent
    ' image drawing to occur and just verbatim copies the bits).
    g1.CompositingMode = Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy
    g1.DrawLine(Pens.Transparent, 0, y, wMax, y)
    g1.CompositingMode = Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver
```

`CompostingMode` is the Key! I was finally trying to fix this lack again in my program, and a Google search turned up this item that has nothing to do with what I searched for (hey, google can read your mind).

[Is Graphics.DrawImage too slow for bigger images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020710/is-graphics-drawimage-too-slow-for-bigger-images)

Wonderful! Now 10 bucks says,  nobody in the whole wide world ever reads this. 755

Comment: this just saved me hours, another almost four years later. was sure that `SourceOver`, which is the default setting, would do that already. until a search turned this up... so much for the 10 bucks

Comment: @dlatikay I can't believe 5 people have up voted this!! If that keeps happening, I'll be broke soon.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the only way to alter the alpha channel is, as you say, to use SetPixel or (of course, much better) pointers. Depending on what you're trying to do to, you *could* get by with creative use of a ColorMatrix. That will let you alter a DrawImage operation in such a way that you can interchange the meaning of R/G/B/A as you draw it. Try this to get an idea:

```
        using ( var bmp = new Bitmap( 100, 100 ) )
        using ( var g = Graphics.FromImage( bmp ) )
        using ( var ia = new ImageAttributes() )
        {
            float R = 1;
            float G = 0;
            float B = 0;
            ia.SetColorMatrix( new ColorMatrix( new float[][] {
                new float[] {1, 0, 0, R, 0},
                new float[] {0, 1, 0, G, 0},
                new float[] {0, 0, 1, B, 0},
                new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}} ) );
            g.Clear( Color.White );
            g.FillEllipse( Brushes.Blue, 10, 10, 30, 30 );
            g.FillEllipse( Brushes.Red, 60, 10, 30, 30 );
            g.FillEllipse( Brushes.Green, 10, 60, 30, 30 );
            g.FillEllipse( Brushes.Black, 60, 60, 30, 30 );
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(
                bmp,
                new Rectangle( 0, 0, 100, 100 ),
                0, 0, 100, 100,
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel,
                ia );
        }
```

Try setting R/G/B to 1 respectively and see how that changes what colors that come out solid/transparent. But, if you should like to alter the alpha channel of the bitmap directly, here's how to do it: [Soft edged images in GDI+.](http://danbystrom.se/2008/08/24/soft-edged-images-in-gdi/)

Comment: Thanks danny. I was hoping a matrix would do it but missed the mark in my efforts. I'll give yours a try and if I don't get anywhere, I'll give up and bypass GDI (I'm stuck with VB & LockBits/Marshall.Copy but that's good enough). But it looks like it will work.