# Is Graphics.DrawImage too slow for bigger images?

Tags: c#, image, c#-4.0, gdi+

I'm currently working on a game and I wish to have a main menu with background image.

However, I find the method `Graphics.DrawImage()` really slow. I have made some measurement. Let's assume that MenuBackground is my resource image with resolution 800 x 1200 pixels. I will draw it onto another 800 x 1200 bitmap (I render everything to a buffer bitmap first, then I scale it and finally draw it onto screen - that's how I deal with the possibility of multiple players' resolutions. But it shouldn't affect it in any way, see the next paragraph).

So I've measured the following code:

```
Stopwatch SW = new Stopwatch();
SW.Start();

// First let's render background image into original-sized bitmap:

OriginalRenderGraphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.MenuBackground,
   new Rectangle(0, 0, Globals.OriginalScreenWidth, Globals.OriginalScreenHeight));

SW.Stop();
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(SW.ElapsedMilliseconds + " milliseconds");
```

The result is quiet surprising to me - the `Stopwatch` measures something between `40 - 50 milliseconds`. And because the background image is not the only thing to be drawn, the whole menu takes about over 100 ms to display, which implicates observable lag.

I have tried to draw it to Graphics object given by Paint event, but the result was `30 - 40 milliseconds` - not much changed.

So, does it mean, that `Graphics.DrawImage()` is unusable for drawing bigger images? If so, what should I do to improve the performance of my game?

Comment: If by "unusable" you mean "slow as a snail in molasses", then yes.  As others have said, give XNA a try.  Stick to 2D sprite rendering until you're used to the XNA framework, then move towards 3D if you're so inclined.

Comment: I'm upvoting that just for the analogy. :)

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Yes, it is too slow.

I ran into this problem several years ago while developing Paint.NET (right from the start, actually, and it was rather frustrating!). Rendering performance was abysmal, as it was always proportional to the size of the bitmap and not the size of the area that it was told to redraw. That is, framerate went down as the size of the bitmap went up, and framerate never went up as the size of the invalid/redraw area went down when implementing OnPaint() and calling Graphics.DrawImage(). A small bitmap, say 800x600, always worked fine, but larger images (e.g. 2400x1800) were very slow. (You can assume, for the preceding paragraph anyway, that nothing extra was going on, such as scaling with some expensive Bicubic filter, which would have adversely affected performance.)

It is possible to force WinForms into using GDI instead of GDI+ and avoid even the creation of a `Graphics` object behind the scenes, at which point you can layer another rendering toolkit on top of that (e.g. Direct2D). However, it's not simple. I do this in Paint.NET, and you can see what's required by using something like Reflector on the class called `GdiPaintControl` in the SystemLayer DLL, but for what you're doing I'd consider it a last resort.

However, the bitmap size you're using (800x1200) should still work OK enough in GDI+ without having to resort to advanced interop, unless you're targeting something as low as a 300MHz Pentium II. Here are some tips that might help out:

- If you are using an opaque bitmap (no alpha/transparency) in the call to `Graphics.DrawImage()`, and especially if it's a 32-bit bitmap with an alpha channel (but you *know* it's opaque, or you don't care), then set `Graphics.CompositingMode` to `CompositingMode.SourceCopy` before calling `DrawImage()` (be sure to set it back to the original value after, otherwise regular drawing primitives will look very ugly). This skips a lot of extra blending math per-pixel.
- Make sure `Graphics.InterpolationMode` isn't set to something like `InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic`. Using `NearestNeighbor` will be the fastest, although if there's any stretching it may not look very good (unless it's stretching by exactly 2x, 3x, 4x, etc.) `Bilinear` is usually a good compromise. You should never use anything but `NearestNeighbor` if the bitmap size matches the area you're drawing to, in pixels.
- Always draw into the `Graphics` object given to you in `OnPaint()`.
- Always do your drawing in `OnPaint`. If you need to redraw an area, call `Invalidate()`. If you need the drawing to happen right now, call `Update()` after `Invalidate()`. This is a reasonable approach since WM_PAINT messages (which results in a call to `OnPaint()`) are "low priority" messages. Any other processing by the window manager will be done first, and thus you could end up with lots of frame skipping and hitching otherwise.
- Using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` as a framerate/tick timer won't work very well. These are implemented using Win32's `SetTimer` and result in WM_TIMER messages which then result in the `Timer.Tick` event being raised, and WM_TIMER is another low priority message which is sent only when the message queue is empty. You're better off using `System.Threading.Timer` and then using `Control.Invoke()` (to make sure you're on the right thread!) and calling `Control.Update()`.
- In general, do not use `Control.CreateGraphics()`. (corollary to 'always draw in `OnPaint()`' and 'always use the `Graphics` given to you by `OnPaint()`')
- I recommend not using the Paint event handler. Instead, implement `OnPaint()` in the class you're writing which should be derived from `Control`. Deriving from another class, e.g. `PictureBox` or `UserControl`, will either not add any value for you or will add additional overhead. (BTW `PictureBox` is often misunderstood. You will probably almost never want to use it.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: you deserve tons of upvotes.For drawing a background grid is there any tip ? TextureBrush seems fast but it doesnt work when you have custom scalling with a zoom factor as it doesnt match

Comment: The best optimization of this post for me was the interpolation mode. Changing `Bilinear` to `NearestNeighbor` made the drawing 8 times quicker.

Comment: Years later you are still helping people out with the painting in winforms

Comment: Can you please clarify your last comment, about PictureBoxes? Why should they not be used, and how are they misunderstood?

Comment: `PictureBox` is for displaying an `Image`, nothing more. If you pretend the class is `sealed`, its use case should be clearer. It's misunderstood because I've often seen code where a new class is created that derives from `PictureBox` and then the author overrides `OnPaint` or whatever and does custom rendering. Don't do that -- just derive directly from `Control` if you want to do custom rendering. And if you just want to show an `Image` or `Bitmap`, use `PictureBox` -- but don't derive a new class from it. Pretend it's sealed.

Comment: @RickBrewster EmguCV developers disagree. "PanAndZoomPictureBox : PictureBox". "ImageBox : PanAndZoomPictureBox".

Comment: For a render loop see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830261/c-winforms-wpf-render-loop/58080188#58080188

Comment: Wow, you made PAINT.net? I'll give you an upvote for that on its own!

Answer (score 8):

Although this is an ancient question and WinForms is an ancient Framework, I would like to share what I have just discovered by accident: drawing a Bitmap into a BufferedGraphics and rendering it afterwards to the graphics context provided by OnPaint is **way** faster than drawing the Bitmap directly to OnPaint's graphics context - at least on my Windows 10 machine.

That's surprising because intuitively I had assumed that it would be slightly slower to copy data twice (and so I thought that this is usually only justified when one wants to do double-buffering manually). But obviously there is something more sophisticated going on with the BufferedGraphics object.

So create a BufferedGraphics in the constructor of the Control that shall host the Bitmap (in my case I wanted to draw a fullscreen bitmap 1920x1080):

```
        using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
        {
            graphicsBuffer = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current.Allocate(graphics, new Rectangle(0,0,Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height));
        }
```

and use it in OnPaint (while voiding OnPaintBackground)

```
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) {/* just rely on the bitmap to fill the screen */}

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {   
        Graphics g = graphicsBuffer.Graphics;

        g.DrawImage(someBitmap,0,0,bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

        graphicsBuffer.Render(e.Graphics);
    }
```

instead of naively defining

```
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) {/* just rely on the bitmap to fill the screen */}

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {   
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(someBitmap,0,0,bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
    }
```

See the following screenshots for a comparison of the resulting MouseMove event frequency (I am implementing a very simple bitmap sketching control). At the top is the version where the Bitmap is drawn directly, at the bottom BufferedGraphics is used. I moved the mouse at about the same speed in both cases.

[image]

Comment: Just ran into this too. Setting `DoubleBuffered = true` on the control (or the form) seems to have the same effect! From 150ms down to 1ms when the only line of code in OnPaint is a call to `e.Graphics.DrawImage`!

Answer (score 3):

GDI+ is probably not the best choice for games. DirectX/XNA or OpenGL should be preferred as they utilize whatever graphics acceleration is possible and are very fast.

Answer (score 3):

GDI+ is not a speed demon by any means.  Any serious image manipulation usually has to go into the native side of things (pInvoke calls and/or manipulation via a pointer obtained by calling `LockBits`.)

Have you looked into XNA/DirectX/OpenGL?.  These are frameworks designed for game development and will be orders of magnitude more efficient and flexible than using a UI framework like WinForms or WPF.  The libraries all offer C# bindings.

You could pInvoke into native code, using functions like [BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but there is overhead associated with crossing the managed code boundary as well.

Comment: I would recommend OpenGL/DirectX too. XNA isn't really the BEST choice per se for a variety of reasons. Ease of use, yes - but in the long run it's a bit of a handicap.

Comment: @ananthonline: You're right, they're worth a mention.  DirectX is superior to OpenGL if you don't care about cross-platform support.  Can you expand on your comment *" in the long run [XNA is] a bit of a handicap"*.  I probably have some holes in my knowledge as I'm not a serious game developer, just a hobby of mine.

Comment: XNA makes several assumptions to its use. One of the serious limitations I can think of is that multiple rendertargets cannot share a depth buffer, making common scenarios like efficiently doing deferred rendering impossible. See here for more info (http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/64179/397431.aspx)

Comment: Also - it does not have a definite future on Metro. I don't know if it will be supported outside of projects like MonoGame (http://monogame.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @ananthonline: Thanks.  I went to far with the "By far the best" comment.  I thought that using DirectX or OpenGL from C# would be cumbersome, but after doing some research it looks like there are some nice C# interfaces I was unaware of.

Comment: it's worth noting that since this was originally posted, XNA has been discontinued.  While it's technically possible to code games in it still, it's incredibly hard and unsupported to even get the development environment to install in the latest versions of visual studio since in their wisdom, they looked for specific versions to support with their installer rather than "all versions higher than x" which means 2017 works with it, but it refuses to install.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this on a menu, but when overriding `OnPaint` of a Form just to paint an image, setting `Form.DoubleBuffered = true` speeds it up massively.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(_bmp, 0, 0);
}
```

With `DoubleBuffered = false` this takes 160ms per update. With `true` it's 1.5ms. It's trivial to hit 60fps and have room to spare.

Tested on .NET 7.0.