# Faster Graphics

Tags: c#, performance, vector, graphics

So I've been messing around with 3D - 2D vector transformations and would like to start writing some fun, simple programs to interact with simple quadric surfaces and such. My question is this:

What are some good ways to make my code more efficient? Are there other C# based programs that I can use for graphics?

I'm working in C# (and definitely want to stay that way),  and I realize that I have been doing this in a pretty inefficient way so far.

I don't know if I can improve my looping, or the fact that I calculate the transformations every time I move the camera, or what, but any help would be awesome!

Here is some example code (draws the surface pictured in image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi1ZQ.png)

```
void ColorSurface(Point3[] S)
    {
        List<Panel> f = new List<Panel>();
        try
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
                {
                    f.Add(new Panel(S[(10 * x) + y], S[(10 * x) + y + 1], S[(10 * x) + y + 11], S[(10 * x) + y + 10], View));
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
        for (int sort = 0; sort < f.Count - 1; sort++)
        {
            Panel temp;
            if (f[sort] > f[sort + 1])
            {
                temp = f[sort + 1];
                f[sort + 1] = f[sort];
                f[sort] = temp;
            }
        }
        using (var g = this.CreateGraphics())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < f.Count; i++)
            {
                double dev = f[i].PM.Z;
                PointF[] R = new PointF[4];
                R[0] = Transform32(f[i].P1);
                R[1] = Transform32(f[i].P2);
                R[2] = Transform32(f[i].P3);
                R[3] = Transform32(f[i].P4);
                try
                {
                    SolidBrush G = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(235, (int)(((255 / Math.PI) * (Math.Atan((dev / 10) + 0.2) + (Math.PI / 2)))), 0, 255 - (int)(((255 / Math.PI) * (Math.Atan((dev / 10) + 0.2) + (Math.PI / 2))))));
                    g.FillPolygon(G, R);
                    g.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), R);
                    DrawPoint(f[i].PM, new Pen(Color.Black, 3));
                }
                 catch { }
            }
            }

    }
```

Comment: for games i'd recommend unity (mono - c#). for everything else WPF ... System.Windows.Media.Media3D namespace

Comment: There you can calculate a mesh once ... and just move the camera

Comment: If you are stuck with a winforms application you still can use WPF Controls by the way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some quick efficiency tips:

1. Everything I said here applies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11025428/1191082 . In particular, you're not doing your drawing in `OnPaint`. Do not use `CreateGraphics`. It's not evil, you're just not structuring your code correctly and it will make things much more difficult later on.
2. You're accessing `List.Count` on every loop iteration. This generally adds a non-inlined method call that you will want to avoid (in general, and repeat after me, "the JIT is not very smart" :)). Recommend a form such as, `for (int sort = 0, count = f.Count; sort < count - 1; sort++)` etc. This is particular important if your code is accessing via an `IList<T>` reference that was handed over from another area (like as a function parameter). Yes, CPUs have pretty good branch prediction nowadays. However, this is still an inefficiency that should absolutely be avoided on hot paths.
3. You allocate a brand new `PointF[]` on every loop iteration. Create it once outside the loop and reuse it.
4. Even worse, you're creating a brand new `SolidBrush` on every loop iteration. *And* you're not calling `Dispose` on it! At the very least you need to use `using`, e.g. `using (SolidBrush G = new SolidBrush(...)) { ... }`.
5. You're also creating two brand new `Pen`s on every loop iteration, even though they're always the same. Create it once and reuse it. Also consider using `Pens.Black` for the first one, which is a static cache that you won't have to manage.

And last, don't do stuff like `catch { }`. That usually goes under "worst practices" sections of style guidelines with "DO NOT DO THIS EVER OR YOU WILL BE FIRED".